# How to replace null values to in map during deserialization in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jackson, objectmapper

I have data class, which is used for place response from some REST service:

```
data class RestResponse(
    val themes: List<Map<String, String?>> = emptyList(),
)
```

and some values inside map could be empty strings.

But there is configuration in project that affect this:

```
enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT)
```

so, all empty strings are casted to null values.

I don't want to fix this setting for the whole project, but only want to empty strings for map in this response don't be cast to null values.

What is the best way to solve this?

As i see there could be different solutions:

1. Write custom deserializer
2. Fix null values after creating an response object

But it would be better for me if i could customize setting

```
enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT)
```

for only this data class.Is it possible?

P.S. - i use Jackson lib for mapping

Comment: Are you using Jackson for the mapping? I cannot tell for sure.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel yes, you're right. Sorry, i forgot to add this information

Comment: The `ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT` feature doesn't do anything unless it wouldn't normally be possible to convert an empty string to the target deserialization type. If the target type is a String (the map values, in your case) this feature has no effect. Something else must be the root of your problem. Can you please share an example of the JSON you're trying to parse?

Comment: yes, you're right. I found out that there was custom deserializer which set null values to each empty string. So that was the problem in my case